# Import component dynamically in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router

I want to import screens based on user id. I created a wrapper component to do this but It doesn't work for nested routes. In vue 2 I can use app instance in router to decide which screen renders but vue 3 I can't do this approach

```html
<script>
  //imports
  export default {
    setup() {
      const decidedComponent = ref();
      const { user } = useAuth();
      const route = useRoute();
      function decide() {
        decidedComponent.value = markRaw(
          defineAsyncComponent(() =>
            user.id === 1
              ? import(`@/screens/1/${route.meta.name}/index.vue`)
              : user.id === 2
              ? route.meta.name
              : import(`@/screens/2/${route.meta.name}/index.vue`)
          )
        );
      }

      return {
        decide,
        decidedComponent,
      };
    },
    beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
      // When first entering the route
      next((vm) => vm.decide());
    },
  };
</script>
<template>
  <component
    v-if="decidedComponent"
    :is="decidedComponent"
    :key="`${decidedComponent.__file}`"
  ></component>
</template>
```

```js
//router

    {
        path: "/customer/:customerId",
        name: "customer",
        component: DecideComponent,
        meta: {
          name: "MultiPages",
        },
        children: [
          {
            path: "details",
            name: "customer.details",
            component: DecideComponent,
            meta: {
              name: "CustomerDetails",
            },
          },
```

It doesn't work for parent route.

Comment: What is the value of `${route.meta.name}` in the parent route? You have some bugs in your logic, the user.id comparison results are the same. Have you tried async importing the DecideComponent in your router.js?

Comment: Try dynamic routing to the correct screen instead: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/dynamic-routing.html

Comment: name in meta is for folder name.Can you share an example ?

Comment: Go read the link I sent, it explains dynamic routes. Also your DecideComponent is expecting these vue files: `@/screens/1/MultiPages/index.vue` and `@/screens/1/CustomerDetails/index.vue`, do these files exist?

Comment: Ultimately you are using the router wrong, re-think your structure and lay it out in an abstract way that is not user dependent. If you want to display certain things use `v-if` for those users, or use a user group. You should not have components imported dynamically like this, this is just bad design. The purpose of VUE sfc is re-usability. I don't see any re-usability in your snippet